# Monitoring a TCP/IP connection for data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm using a TCP/IP connection to talk to a laser and control its functions. Initially, I make the connection to the laser as a client using the socket.connect() method, but then the both the laser and computer has "equal status and so both must monitor for received transmissions as well as sending requests" (as said in the TCP/IP protocol manual). How do I know configure/code so that I can monitor for data even though I connected as a client? I have tried using recv() in a loop, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Using python 2.7

Thanks for your Help

Andrew

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import json
import time


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def connect(IP_addrs = '192.168.1.222', port = 39933):
    s.settimeout(10)
    s.connect((IP_addrs,port))
    myIP = s.getsockname()[0]
    msg = {"transmission_id" : [1] , "op":"start_link", "parameters":{ "ip_address": myIP}}
    reply = send(msg)
    print reply

def send(msg):
    s.sendall( json.dumps( { "message" : msg } ) )
    r = s.recv(1024)
    r = json.loads(r)
    return r["message"]["parameters"]

def ping():
    msg = {'transmission_id' : [2], 'op':'ping', 'parameters':{'text_in':'TESTING'}}
    reply = send(msg)
    print reply['text_out']


def move_wave_m(wavelength):
    msg = {'transmission_id' : [3], 'op':'set_wave_m', 'parameters':{'wavelength': [wavelength],
           'report':['finished']}}
    reply = send(msg)
    print reply
    while True:
        reply = s.recv(1024)
        if not reply:
            break
        print reply

def poll_wave_m():
    msg = {'transmission_id' : [4], 'op':'poll_wave_m'}
    return send(msg)



connect()
ping()
s.settimeout(None)
move_wave_m(725.0000)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on Unix (Linux, Mac OS), but have some thoughts to propose for Windows too.
This is a working skeleton of a program that does some mandatory stuff with a device and then waits for input. In this particular case I'm pretending you want to have realtime access to your laser (like a terminal access) and watch for responses at the same time.

```
import sys
import select
import socket

shell_is_active = True
sock = socket.socket()
# connect the socket


def do_mandatory_stuff():
    # sendall(...)
    pass


def interpret_user_input(user_input):
    # in case you want shell access to the laser
    print user_input


def main():
    do_mandatory_stuff()

    # wait for socket or user IO
    while shell_is_active:
        pending_inputs, _1, _2 = select.select([sys.stdin, sock], [], [], 0)
        if not pending_inputs:
            continue

        for input_source in pending_inputs:
            if input_source is sys.stdin:
                interpret_user_input(sys.stdin.readline())

            if input_source is sock:
                print sock.recv(1024)  # use more advanced things if needed

    sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The crucial thing here is `select.select([sys.stdin, sock], [], [], 0)` - it is a non-blocking call of [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) which returns a list of *descriptors* ready for reading (`pending_inputs`), writing (`_1`), and other conditions (`_2`).

I made it non-blocking in case if some background work is needed to be done in the same thread alongside with waiting for IO. Otherwise, feel free to remove `0` parameter and consequent `if` block.

This line will work only for Unix-like systems (Linux, Mac OS). In order to make it work for Windows, use `select.select([sock], [], [], 0)`. Unfortunately you'll have to create a separate [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#) for catching stdin on this platform. It may look like this:

```
import threading

sock_lock = threading.Lock()

def interpret_user_input():
    while True:
        inp = raw_input()
        with sock_lock:
            sock.sendall(inp)

...
def main():
    user_io_thread = threading.Thread(target=interpret_user_input)
    user_io_thread.run()

    # do mandatory stuff and then call select in a loop
    # don't forget "with sock_lock:" each time you use the socket!
    # (and other objects shared between threads as well)
```